# Updating with ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to update a hidden field created with...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(page, fieldName, initialValue);
```

When the page posts back to the server the field is already registered, calling ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField again seems to append to the field.  e.g.

On the first request...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(page, "MyHidden", "foo");
```

Page posts back and you make a second call...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(page, "MyHidden", "bar");
```

Value of the hidden field becomes "foo,bar".
I would prefer the value to be "bar".
  Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE:  The normal behavior should result in the second call setting the hidden field to "bar".  I've yet to determine how to replicate this issue.  I should change my question to.  Has anyone observed this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It contains only one value at any point of time:

```
    if(!IsPostBack)
            ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(this, "MyHidden", "foo");
    else
            ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(this, "MyHidden", "bar");
```

Output is "foo" and after postback it's "bar".

Comment: You seem to be correct.  I cannot replicate the behavior I'm seeing in a smaller web application.  My question obviously doesn't include all the information required to replicate the observed behavior.